# How to send Facebook permission "pages_manage_leads" for review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook application requires "`pages_manage_leads`" permission. I use Graph API v2.5. The problem is that in [Facebok Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference) next to "`pages_manage_leads`" section we have:

> **Review**
>
> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

But when I go to the application on Facebook developers website:

> *Status & Review -> Items in Review -> Add Items to this Submission*

I don't see an option to review "`pages_manage_leads`".

Could you advice me what is the solution in this situation? How can I review the permission?

Comment: Filed a bug on Facebook, let's see what they will reply...

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to app details.
2. Find App Center Listed Platforms and press on button "Configure app center permissions".
3. Enter permission "pages_manage_leads"

That's all

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't change anything. General users still can't provide pages_manage_leads permission.

Comment: please check the bug reports also

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1659842364274331/ there is a bug,  getting leads bulk copy by form id and accountid/ads

Comment: before you will start developing an application ).

Comment: And the other one bug when you are trying to get leads in real time (webhooks) https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/512804228888393/

Comment: Thanks, but the first bug is not confirmed and the second is not related with my issue. Maybe you didn't understand the problem. I have everything working fine for users who are the application administrators because they can provide all needed permissions. So I am getting realtime leads on my backend without any problems. What I want is to allow general users to use the application and now I can't do this because general users can't provide "pages_manage_leads" permission for the reason it should be reviewed and there is no way to put "pages_manage_leads" for review.